# Send Email upon Registration to Author of node

Tags: rules

I have searched and can not find anything similar.

I have a Rule, Event = send email after someone registers for an event. 
I have the rule sending to the user just fine. However, I am trying to also email the Author of the page and I can find the correct replacement pattern.

I have an action Fetch Entity by ID Value=registration - DATA-Selector=registration:author:uid

I have tried many patterns:

`[node:author:mail] mail - Nothing happens
[registration:author:uid] uid - give me the logged in user id
[registration:author:uid] reg-a-uid  (this give mne the id of the logged in user- not the author on the page.)
[node:author:uid] node-a-uid
[site:author:uid] site-a-uid
[registration:author] reg-author - show logged in user
[registration:author:mail] reg-author-mail - show logged in user`

I am at a loss when trying to figure out how to pull the author of the node/page to email them. 
Any ideas???
Thanks

[EDIT]

I was able to get the Author to print out.

```
author: [registration:entity:author]
```

Any ideas to pull the author first name, email and phone number???

Please any little thought would help.
Thanks

Comment: how you are handling registration process? looks like registration is an entity itself,are you using any contrib module for registration?

Comment: We are using the Registration module. We have a live events page with the registration block on the page to register for that event. I can choose from a few different options, entity is not one. Node, registration, user, profile, and a few others.

Answer (score 0):

So after getting the base set I needed to connect to the table for the users profile information.

So for first name it would be:

```
[registration:entity:author:profile-main:field_first_name]
```

So for phone number it would be:(field_office is what they called the Office Phone field.)

```
[registration:entity:author:profile-main:field_office]
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: I'm a "rules" fan (can you tell from my rep specific to its tag?). Therefor i'm curious what you mean by "connect to the table". Can you explain that AbitMORE please?